# PHP/Mysql Comment Box basic coding issue

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I would like to add a simple contact box to my web site. I have followed on line tutorials but they never seem to work the way they are meant to: 
I have set up a table on phpMyadmin called comment with table called comment and 3 columns: id,name and comment. I have used this code for the comment box page...index.php

```
    <html>
<form action="post_comment.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" value="Your Name"><br>
<textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="2">Enter your query and contact details</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then i have another page called post_comment.php with the mysql coding on it...

```
    <?php

     mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     mysql_select_db("comment");

     $name = $_POST["name"];
     $comment = $_POST["comment"];

     $comment_length = strlen($comment);

     if($comment_length > 100)

    {
    header("location: index.php?error=1")
    }
    else
   {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment VALUES('','$name','$comment')")
   header("location: index.php")
   }

   ?>
```

BUT once i enter details in the input boxes instead of the details being sent to my table i get this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable

```
(T_VARIABLE) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\contact1.php on line 16
```

Line 16 of my code only has the else statement written on it. Could someone have a look as i know it's basic but I'm just starting out. Thanks in Advance.Paul

Comment: You are missing several ; (last 3 function calls)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Ive got the code working from the answer's I have received. I am a bit of a simpleton just starting out with php so this advice was invaluable. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PLEASE, please, look up and understand SQL Injection. Do not put user-text directly into your queries or you're just asking for someone to screw with you.  And if "root" is really your login, even worse...utilize a user account with less permissions. Also, you should use PDO or mysqli, as the mysql extension is deprecated.

That said, here is your code, somewhat fixed to sanitize the user-input and fixed syntax errors:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("comment");

$name           = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"], $conn);
$comment        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["comment"], $conn);

$comment_length = strlen($comment);

if($comment_length > 100)
{
    header("location: index.php?error=1");
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment VALUES('','$name','$comment')");
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I have just read about sql injection and will make sure when I code a site I will be very careful with database security. This code is only for me to test site on my pc but when i am uploading ill make sure it's secure. I will start using bdo or mysqli if that is now standard. Again I appreciate your help and advise. I am excited now that the code works. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Watch your syntax. I have corrected it below but every function call in the if statement had no ';'.

```
<?php

 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("comment");

 $name = $_POST["name"];
 $comment = $_POST["comment"];

 $comment_length = strlen($comment);

 if($comment_length > 100)
 {
     header("location: index.php?error=1");
 }
 else
 {
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment VALUES('','$name','$comment')");
     header("location: index.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice. I though it must be a basic syntax but I just could not see the problem. I will keep an eye out for this. Anyway your code worked perfect. I was so excited to see my entries entered in my database. I have been messing about with web design for year's but the development side always seemed frightening. I am going to muddle on with php though and try to pick up information on the way. Thanks again you made my day! Cheers